# making Quartz scheduler persistent without JDBC

Tags: java, mongodb, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler

We're building an app around [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/), and have a need to run cron-like jobs periodically. I've used [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) before for this kind of thing when projects were based around an RDBMS with JDBC.

Since we're already using MongoDB for our main datastore in this project, I'd prefer to not introduce an RDBMS simply to persist Quartz jobs, but there doesn't seem to be any kind of [JobStore](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/tutorial/TutorialLesson09.html) implementatiom for MongoDB.

Can anyone recommend either a way to back Quartz with MongoDB, or a simple alternative to Quartz? My needs are fairly simple (run various java jobs with some manner of configuration, à la cron).

Comment: I don't know of any such product, but then I've never heard of Quartz before today. Given that there's a clear [JobStore](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/org/quartz/spi/JobStore.html) interface, it seems like you should be able to use the MongoDB Java Driver and implement such a store. Not as good as "free and working", but I'm not sure you're going to find such a thing at this point in time.

Comment: Implementing the JobStore interface is optional for Quartz -- you only need if (1) you are running in a clustered environment or (2) you use persistant job properties that need to be preserved between JVM restarts. Otherwise, simply instantiate the scheduler and add jobs at on startup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We run quartz with Spring and it's just an XML file with the jobs defined and cron expressions.

Declare a job in Spring:

```
  <bean name="myJob" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">
    <property name="concurrent" value="false"/>
    <property name="targetBeanName" value="myBean"/>
    <property name="targetMethod" value="myScheduledMethod"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="myJobTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="myJob"/>
    <!-- every 30s -->
    <property name="cronExpression" value="0/30 * * * * ?"/>
  </bean>
```

Quartz Wiring:

```
  <bean id="schedulerFactoryBean" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="triggers">
      <!-- List of batch jobs to be fed to the scheduler. -->
      <list>
        <ref bean="myTrigger"/>
      </list>
    </property>
  </bean>
```

Run it with:

```
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception
    {
        new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("jobs-context.xml");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is more or less what I settled on. We're not using Spring, so I just point my quartz.properties at a quartz-config.xml file, as described here: http://www.openscope.net/2010/02/05/quartz-scheduled-jobs/  

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: That's just running embedded, right? Which is fine for certain jobs, but for persistent jobs, particularly non-recurring ones, you want to have a persistent store backing it so that you can survice take-downs etc.

Answer (score 9):

***Edit***: Latest implementation https://github.com/michaelklishin/quartz-mongodb forked from below repo

---

I wrote a MongoDB JobStore for Quartz which is located here: https://github.com/mulesoft/quartz-mongodb It doesn't support everything, but it works for a bunch of use cases.

Comment: Does this implementation support recurring alarms? Will it reload the triggers from db automatically and schedule them on application restarts?